# Can a charged particle pass through a superconductor?

Tags: superconductivity

Can a charged particle pass through a superconductor?

I think it is impossible, because the superconductor will induce an infinite electric field which keeps the particle away.

Comment: Why is the superconductor producing an (infinite) electric field?

Comment: Superconductors can conduct electricity meaning electron (a charged particle) is being passed.

Comment: @BMS because the particle can reach the infinite small distance from the superconductor.so is it means that it can induce electric field with infinite strength

Comment: *[citation needed]*

Comment: What happens when an infinite charge (or momentum) meets an infinite field?  I know this is an old metaphysical joke, but maybe it'll help show why your question is a bit off.

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar but the electric field is some kind of draging force

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes and no.

"Yes", because a superconductor is able to transfer charges from one contacted edge to an other one.

"No" (somehow), because charges do not flow inside the superconductors, but at its edges. This is an old result due to London, showing that the current flows always at the edges of a superconductor, over a distance known as the penetration length. For more details see F. London, *Superfluids, Volume I: Macroscopic Theory of Superconductivity* (Dover Publications, Inc., 1961).

So in a sense you're right. One usually prefers to say that the magnetic field is zero inside the superconductor instead of this curious statement that the electric field is infinite. That's the reason why there is no current in the bulk, and only at the edge.

Comment: so it depends on some condirtions?i

Comment: @lai Absolutely not ! It transmits charges on the edge, that's all. Then the magnetic field can still be zero in the bulk, and a current can still flow across the superconductor.

Comment: Sorry but maybe you misunderstand my question. I suppose that a free electrical particle fly towards the superconductor and will pass through it. But at the same time, the superconductor will induce some electric field which keep the particle away. As the superconductor has some special propriety, I believe that the particle will never pass through it

Comment: @Lai So then, as the electron approaches the superconductor, you expect dipolar moment to form. Should exist some literature about that for superconductor. I think it's called the working function in the case of semi-conductor (the energy it costs to add one electron to the semiconductor, and Jackson's book might be full of such calculation for metallic spheres). But then it's not the problem of passing an electron *through* a superconductor, but more the question how *approaching* a charge to the superconductor change the distribution of charges inside the superconductor.

Comment: Exactly I know that the movement will change the distribution of the charge inside the superconductor. But I wonder whether the dragging force, which is the consequence of the distribution change, is strong enough to push the particle back. is there a theory to prove it?